# Org-babel `set` src-block-info?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

We have `org-babel-get-src-block-info` and `org-babel-view-src-block-info`.

Is there anything similar to programatically (or preferably interactively) changing the choices from the `src-block-info`?

If not, what would be the recommended way to do that?

Comment: In a src block header line there is support for `completing-read` insertion of arguments after ":" with `org-babel-header-arg-expand`.